# Do suggested edits eventually age away if not reviewed?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, aged-away

Votes to close and such eventually age away if not enough people vote.  What about suggested edits - if an edit is neither approved/rejected by 2 users, does it eventually timeout too?  Or does it stay in the queue indefinitely?   I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this one way or another.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, suggested edits don't age away.

There is a little chance an edit stays long in the queue as the OP gets an inbox notification and the edit goes into the queue where, specially at Stack Overflow, enough robo-reviewers click 'Approve' ... eh, I mean enough reviewers spend some time on evaluating your suggestion and either approve, improve or reject with one of the canned or a custom reason.

Users with review privilege who visit the post see an indicator next to the edit link to indicate that a review is waiting. Clicking edit will enable them to accept/reject as well.

You can use the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/350400/maxium-minutes-of-suggested-edit-before-final) to determine the maximum time in minutes for a suggested edit to get approved/rejected:

```
select max(datediff(hh, creationdate, coalesce(approvaldate, rejectiondate)))
from suggestededits
where approvaldate is not null
or rejectiondate is not null
```

On [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) the maximum for a suggested-edit to sit in the queue is 102 hours while the average is 5 hours.

If you have a pending edit that takes way longer then the average for the site you're active one, you can try to hop in to a chat room and ask if someone can help and if that doesn't finalize the edit, ask on the site specific meta.

Comment: FYI, I asked because an edit of mine has been pending for 3 days.

Comment: Which site @ThaddeusB

Comment: Was going to click the upvote but noticed the robo part... *cough cough*

Comment: [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).  The [edit in question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9514) was approved a couple minutes after your answer. :)

Comment: @ThaddeusB that's the "risk" in beta sites with low traffic and low amount of active users, same way that flags can wait for days on any site, so are suggested edits on those sites. Not much you can, or should, do. Just keep being active and gain enough rep to be able to edit yourself.

Comment: umm... I get 22507 for Stack Overflow. Some poor soul waited over two weeks for his/her edit to be reviewed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't say there is no chance that your suggested edit sits long in the queue ;)

Comment: I suspect it's remnant of the "zombies" era, when edits to orphaned tag wiki didn't go away until manually cleared by a dev.